# Fragments app development

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

https://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle#comment-39628

iam following the above link to develop fragments in my android app but iam struck in this particular fragment if this error is resolved the app will work fine
can you make me know where i went wrong

[image]

[image]

added 2nd picture to make to everyone clear that iam facing error when i use getSupportFragmentManager()

check out this screenshot too

[image]

Comment: does fragment2 is id of your container?

Comment: "if this error is resolved the app will work..." so we have to guess what is the error?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: inconvertible types is the error

Comment: i copy pasted the code as it is from the URL i entered in question

Comment: cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.fragment' to 'com.example.v_krkoru.kcfragments.TextFragment'

Comment: Post the actual code here, not a picture of it. See the how-to-ask page and other recent/up-voted questions for examples to emulate.

Comment: regarding your latest problem... try using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 different types of Fragments:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

You have to use the corresponding `FragmentManager` for them.
Either `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using support library. The reference class of your TextFragment is [android.support.v4.app.fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) instead [android.app.fragment.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

You need to use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);
```

Good luck

Emre

Comment: hey buddy if i use getSupportFragmentManager() in that particular android.support.v4.app.fragment

Comment: still iam getting error it is working fine if i use android.app.fragment with getFragmentManager()

Comment: Then you are using both classes in same project. You should check your every fragment and activity to have same reference.

Comment: I can clearly see from imports that ListFragments referenced from Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you are using getFrgamentManager() but as you can see on your imports at the top you are using at least one support library which means your TextFragment could be extending the android.support.v4.app.Fragment class.

This means to make it work you need to call for the supportFragmentManager instead of the regular FragmentManager.

You do this by changing:

```
TextFragment txt = (TextFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

to be:

```
TextFragment txt = (TextFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

When using fragments just make sure that your imports at the top are as you expect them to be. When using the android.support.v4.app.Fragment you need to use the supportFragmentManager.

EDIT:

As your edits, and your screenshots show, you can't invoke getSupportFragmentManager() within the ListFragment. Which means you need to do:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: hey buddy if i use getSupportFragmentManager() in that particular android.support.v4.app.fragmen

Comment: still iam getting error it is working fine if i use android.app.fragment with getFragmentManager()

Comment: @KrishnaChaitu does your activity extends AppCompatActivity?If not add this line in dependency   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'  and make your activity to extend AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask with those comments. If you look at @woodii 's answer it is much more concise. Depending on the type of Fragment class you are extending use the appropriate FragmentManager. If you are still getting error can you post the code for your TextFragment so that we can see which Fragment it is that you are trying to use? Also is it the same error or a different one?

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan i posted new screenshot of mine trying your answer and it is not working

Comment: @KrishnaChaitu sorry you should use getFragmentManager() in fragment

Comment: Your screenshot is only saying you can't call getSupportFragmentManager(), just do getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() when you're within a ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment can be imported from two packages `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` so there me missmatch of import class between `TextFragment` and `MenuFragment`.
so replace in `MenuFragment`

> import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

with

> import android.app.ListFragment

because there may be `classCastEception`